# How do I get the information in the hoverbox of my plotly figure to be reordered when I have hovermode set to 'x unified'?

Tags: python, plotly

I have built a plotly figure that mostly consists of go.Scatter traces. Each of these traces have slightly different hovertemplates, but I want the information in the hoverbox to be consolidated, so I set the hovermode to 'x unified', which solves my main issue, but I have another small problem that I'd like to resolve.

A very basic reconstruction of my code looks like this:

```
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data'
iris_df = pd.read_csv(url,header=None,encoding='utf-8')
iris_df.columns = ['sepal length','sepal width','petal length', 'petal width', 'class']

test_fig =  go.Figure()

class_colors = {'Iris-setosa':'blue', 'Iris-versicolor':'green', 'Iris-virginica':'purple'}

for group in iris_df['class'].unique():
    iris_df_class = iris_df[iris_df['class']==group]
    test_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=iris_df_class['sepal length'],
                                 y= iris_df_class['petal length'],
                                 mode='markers',
                                 marker=dict(size=10, color=class_colors[group], symbol=1),
                                 text= group,
                                 hoverinfo='text',
                                 hovertemplate = '<i>Sepal length</i>: %{x:.2f} <extra></extra>',
                                 name= group,
                                 showlegend=True,
                                 legendgroup=group))

    iris_df_class_over_6 = iris_df_class[iris_df_class['sepal length']>6]
    test_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=iris_df_class_over_6['sepal length'],
                                 y= iris_df_class_over_6['petal length']+0.5,
                                 mode='markers',
                                 marker=dict(size=12, color=class_colors[group], symbol=5),
                                 name='trace2',
                                 meta=iris_df_class_over_6['petal width']/iris_df_class_over_6['sepal width'],
                                 hovertemplate='<i>Petal length</i>: %{y:.2f} <br><i>Petal/sepal width ratio</i>: %{meta:0.2f} <extra></extra>',
                                 showlegend=False,
                                 legendgroup=group))

    for s,p in zip(iris_df_class_over_6['sepal length'], iris_df_class_over_6['petal length']):
        test_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[s,s],
                                      y=[p,p+0.5],
                                      mode='lines',
                                      marker_line_width = 2,
                                      line_color=class_colors[group],
                                      name='trace-intermediate',
                                      hoverinfo='skip',
                                      showlegend=False,
                                      legendgroup=group))

test_fig.update_layout(xaxis_title="sepal length", yaxis_title="petal length", hovermode='x unified')
test_fig.show()
```

Which produces a plot like this:
[image: plot example1]

Upon looking at the hoverbox, one can see that the trace for Iris-setosa class (in blue) is placed at the top of the hoverbox, followed by Iris-versicolor (green) and then Iris-virginica (purple). If a given trace is not present at a certain point, the order is still maintained (minus the non-present trace)
[image: plot example2]

Now what I would like to do is to organize this order so that the purple trace goes on top, followed by the green, and then the blue at the bottom. I have tried checking the documentation, but it's not clear what I can do to change the order of the information in the hover box. Does anybody know what could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traces and their respective information in the hoverbox and in the legend follow the order of trace instances in the [figure's `data`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Figure.html) tuple :

```py
fig.data[0] # 1st trace
fig.data[1] # 2nd trace
# ...
```

Because you use `go.Figure.add_trace()`, which append the added trace to the list, the order you have follows the trace group order dictated by `iris_df['class'].unique()` :

```py
print(iris_df['class'].unique())
#> ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
```

So you would need to either :

- reorder the list of iris classes, eg. iterating the list backward :

  ```py
  for group in iris_df['class'].unique()[::-1]:
    # ...
  ```
- Or even simpler, just reorder the traces in the data tuple afterwards :

  ```py
  fig.data = fig.data[::-1]
  ```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's an obvious set up that I totally missed before, thanks! But I must ask, is there any way to reorder the traces in the hoverbox other than changing the order in which they are added to the figure? In my actual code, I have the traces added in a way that are relative to each other, and changing the order might get a little sticky.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned it in the first place, you can reorder the traces in the figure's data tuple directly (afterwards creation). See revised answer.